# Filling between curves only when a given curve is larger than the other

Tags: python, matplotlib, fill

When I try to fill between two curves, for example in the following way:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X=np.linspace(-3.,3.,100)
Y= X**2
plt.fill_between(X,1.,Y,color='red',alpha=0.4)

plt.show()
```

The filling is between the two curves, no matter which one has larger values. Is there an option to specify that I want the filling only when one of the two curves (say `Y`) is larger than the other?

Answer (score 2):

add a conditional statement to your fill_between

...fill_between(...where=(Y > X)...)

you could also add a second with a different color to indicate X>Y

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to do it using the parameter `where` in the following way

```
plt.fill_between(X,1.,Y,color='red',alpha=0.4,where=Y>1.)
```